# TCP reset after SYN ACK possibly related to "no route to host"

Tags: routing, tcp, handshake

I have a problem with one of our clients trying to initiate a TCP connection to our server but it fails.

In `tcpdump`I see, that the client's device sends a `SYN` packet to which our server correctly replies with a `SYN ACK`. Immediately after that, our server receives a `RST` packet. After a few seconds the procedure repeats. Strangely enough, the connection is correctly established from time to time (about every 2 days around 8:30 am).

I have tried redirecting the packets to another server but get the same problem with that server.

Today I tried connecting the other way round. Our client currently does not have a port opened in his firewall, but I tried connecting anyways to see what happens. I used `ssh` to try the connection from different machines, here is what I discovered:

From my personal computer (Mac OS X 10.10): `ssh: connect to host x.x.x.x port 22: Connection refused`

From the server that is receiving the `SYN`packets (Debian 8): `ssh: connect to host x.x.x.x port 22: No route to host`

From another server in a different hosting center (Debian 7): `ssh: connect to host x.x.x.x port 22: No route to host`

From another server in a larger company (Debian 7): `ssh: connect to host x.x.x.x port 22: Operation timed out`

The response I get from my personal computer at home is what I expect if the port is not opened in the firewall, but I am confused by the different outputs I get from the different servers.

Pinging the client's IP from any of these machines works fine.

Could I be looking at a routing problem here, where my `SYN-ACK` packages are routed incorrectly and therefor (almost) never reach the client? Do you have any suggestions on how to tackle the problem? Should I contact the client's ISP, or maybe my server provider?

Thank you for your help.

**UPDATE 1:**

I did some further research on Jeff's Questions. Here are my results:

`IP TTL SYN: 55
IP TTL RST: 59`

I am currently waiting on the client to grant me access to his network, so I cannot currently see if he receives the `SYN-ACK` or if he sends the `RST`

Traceroute:

 `1  x.x.x.x  25.793 ms  5.516 ms  5.516 ms
 2  x.x.x.x  4.140 ms  4.172 ms  4.166 ms
 3  x.x.x.x  4.158 ms  4.147 ms  4.139 ms
 4  x.x.x.x  9.855 ms  9.877 ms  9.874 ms
 5  x.x.x.x  15.506 ms !X  15.753 ms !X  15.970 ms !X`

The traceroute from my computer at home ist the same on the last two hops. Both traceroutes have 5 hops.

There is no firewall or load balancer at the server end.

The routing tables look good on the servers receiving the `no route to host`. They mainly consist of the default route and the local subnet route both working without a problem on all other occasions.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to leave a question so these are more questions than answers, but they should point you in the right direction or allow others to provide more insights into the issue.

```
-What is the IP TTL (or hop limit if IPv6) in the SYN and RST?
-What does a capture from the client show?  
    -Does it receive the SYN-ACK, and does it send the RST?
-What does a traceroute look like?
    -How many hops between the server and the client?  
-Is there a firewall, load balancer or other network 
 device fronting  (NAT, VIP) the server?
-What do the routing tables look like for the servers 
 receiving the No Route to Host?
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. I added the information to my original post. Using the information I gathered, It seems like the client's router sends out the `RST` packets, as the original `SYN` packet has a TTL of 55, but the `RST` only of 59, witch corresponds exactly to the 5 hops in between the server and the client's public IP. Hopefully I can get access to the client's router and find out more there.
I am a little confused about the 4 hops difference, as the client is a private household and I would have expected no more than 2 hops there.

Answer (score 0):

It all comes down to a configuration problem.
The client granted me access to his network today and I found out, that he basically had two devices with the same IP-Address, resulting in a routing problem in his network.

Changed one of the IP-Addresses: Solved.

Thank you for your help.